# CSS positioning involving a fixed width and the remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a container with a width of 100% that contains 2 div,
the first 1 has a fixed width of 50px and the second one needs to occupy all the remaining space (if I give it width: 100% it will obviously fall)

Here's a sample simplified markup:

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 50%; border:1px solid black;">

<div style="width: 50px; border: 1px solid green;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;"></div>

<div style="width: auto; border: 1px solid red;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;"></div>

</div>
```

Of course I don't want any solutions that use javascript or event handlers on the window resize event

[image]

Comment: I guess display: table-cell or something similar would fix it?

Comment: It could. Why don't you give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

On the first child div set `float:left;`

on the second child set: `overflow:hidden` (or auto). This triggers a block formatting context - which causes the second div to fill the remaining horizontal width.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yHD8d/)

```
.container
{
    width: 100%;height: 50%; border:1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}
.left
{
    width: 50px; border: 1px solid green;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;
    float:left;
}

.right
{
    width: auto; border: 1px solid red;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

One important advantage with this method is that it is cross-browser. (no css3 needed)

### Solution 2

Set `position:absolute` on the first child div and set on the second child div: `padding-left:50px` - making use of box-sizing property to place that padding within the box.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yHD8d/1/)**

```
.container
{
    width: 100%;height: 50%; border:1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.left
{
    width: 50px; border: 1px solid green;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.right
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `margin-left:50px` and leave it as a block element. If you have additional padding for the first div then use `margin-left` accordingly. Check the box model of div 1 in console.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#div1  {
    position:fixed; // absolute can be used
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
}
#div2 {
    margin-left:50px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar it's working thanks. But please fix the "postion" typo

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar actually there's a problem with having it fixed, I cannot have this div as fixed as it will affect the document

Comment: Hey @JadJoubran, see `html` and `body` with no content in it have zero height. I have fixed it in first selector. The second selector selects your first div and add fixed position (the div gets out of the flow and will be positioned according to the document). The `top:0` and `bottom:0` works to give your first div full height. I have also added `height:100%`, just to make sure it covers whole screen vertically and atlast, `width` property. On the other hand, the second div which is in flow of document and is a block element, means it will automatically cover all the space and will not allow..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37245/discussion-between-muhammad-talha-akbar-and-jad-joubran)

Answer (score 1):

I Have tried this using the css Calc() function

```
#div2
{
/*Used -54 as all divs have thier border of 1px*/    
width: -moz-calc(100% - 54px);
width: -webkit-calc(100%-54x);
width: calc(100%-54x);
}
```

Check the Demo fiddle here [**DemoFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TzHrM/7/)

This works with any width as the width are getting calculated.

Reference links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/

Comment: @PatsyIssa check my updated fiddle with support for browsers which do not support calc.